# Rounding a calculation result to two decimal places inside a calculation using python

Tags: python, decimal, rounding

Very new to coding and Python. I'm trying to limit the result of a calculation to two decimal places, or however many I want. Found out about using decimals through Google, but I can't get my code to work.

What I started with

```
amount_per_day = amount_of_money/currency_amount
print("If you are going to spend " + str(amount_of_money) + " " + str(destination_currency) + " that means that you can spend up to " + str(amount_per_day) + " " + Home_currency + " per day to remain in budget.")
```

What I tried

```
from decimal import Decimal
amount_per_day = Decimal(amount_of_money/currency_amount)
amount_per_day_to_two_decimal_places = round(amount_per_day,2)
print("If you are going to spend " + str(amount_of_money) + " " + str(destination_currency) + " that means that you can spend up to " + str(amount_per_day) + " " + Home_currency + " per day to remain in budget.")
```

**Result**

If you are going to spend 2000.0 EUR that means that you can spend up to 1818.181818181818016455508768558502197265625 GBP per day to remain in budget.

The codes works, but I don't need the answer to 39 decimals places.

Comment: Two comments: your post is not properly formatted, please edit it. Also, do research before posting, the answer to your question is just one click away in google!

Answer (score 0):

just use `round(x, 2)` where `x` is your variable

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the amount_per_day calculated with 39 decimal places, you could simply remove them with the build in function "round"

round works like this: `round(float_num, num_of_decimals)`
so in your case you do `amount_per_day = round(amount_per_day, 2)`

I also recommend you replacing all your nasty string adding in your print statement with f-strings like this:

```
print(f"If you are going to spend {str(amount_of_money)}
      {str(destination_currency)} that means that you can
      spend up to {str(amount_per_day)} {Home_currency} per
      day to remain in budget.")
```

It looks a lot cleaner and its actually also faster

Answer (score 0):

Python has an inbuilt function [round](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round). It is covered in depth in the documentation.

So in your case, the result you are looking for is `round(amount_per_day, 2)`. Note, this will change the output to 2 decimal places (so will effectively cut off the remaining ones after the second decimal point), and will also round to the nearest *even* value in the even it is halfway between nearest values.

Answer (score 0):

To roundoff you can use the following:

```
value = 1818.181818181818016455508768558502197265625    
print(round(value, 2))
```

You can use the following to format your text.

```
print('you can spend %.2f GBP per day' % value)
```